# TYPO3 Exception #1294587217: when upgrading from 6.2.6 to 7.6.20

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am trying to upgrade a website from TYPO3 6.2.6 to 7.6.20 but I getting this error when I access the front end:

```
#1294587217: The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type `PAGE` with typeNum=0 configured.
```

I have:

- Created a backup and copy of my website
- Installed TYPO3 7.6.20 on the copied site

I can't get the frontend to display.

Comment: Did you run the migration (upgrade) wizzard in install tool after the update to 7.6 ?

Comment: Did you include all need static templates? Did you check PAGE object in TypoScript Object Browser?

Comment: Did you adapt domain specific settings / domain records (your copy probably will run with another domain than the original)?

Comment: @SteffenMächtel I did run the upgrade wizard then all the steps in the important actions section.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling how do i include all the static templates? I have only one template and it seems to be empty

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ my original site was on e.g www.mysite.com then the copy on prod.mysite.com. On Typo3 backend i pointed the copy to the dev.mysite.com

Comment: why do you use different domains for FE and BE? anyway: is the domain for your FE known everywhere? (domain-record, realurl-config, absRefPrefix or baseURL if you use it, typoscript conditions. Have you configured one page as `root`? TS is missing => have you tried to insert a minimal TS on your root-page? have you inspected the active TS for your page you intend as rootpage?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ bothe the FE & BE point to the same domain: dev.mysite.com. I noticed some extentions like bootsrap package were deactivated in the new version. I activated them but still receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the typoscript?

Start with the TSOB and inspect if you have a `page` object definition in your root page.

You might replace it with a dummy:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = This is my special content!
```

make sure you make your typoscript template a root-template.